# Map OAuth2 user attributes to Object prior to controller method call

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

### What I have currently

I'm currently implementing an OIDC Resource Provider for my company. They use their intern OIDC servers, which I managed to work with by following this example: https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2login-demo/tree/linkedin

I'm now able to retrieve user information from the Authorization Server, like [that](https://github.com/jgrandja/oauth2login-demo/blob/linkedin/src/main/java/sample/web/MainController.java):

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some/route")
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping("/some/route")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        String userInfoEndpointUri = authorizedClient.getClientRegistration()
                .getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri();
        Map userAttributes = this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri(userInfoEndpointUri)
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Map.class)
                .block();
        String firstName = (String) userAttributes.get("first_name");
        String lastName = (String) userAttributes.get("last_name");
        ...
    }

}
```

### What I'd like

I am now searching for a solution to map the `userAttributes` to an Object prior to
the controller method call, so that I get e.g.:

```java
@GetMapping("/some/route")
public ResponseEntity<?> getSomething(MyCostumUserBean user) {
    String firstName = user.getFirstName();
    String lastName = user.getLastName();
    ...
}
```

I read something about the `ChannelInterceptor` and `HandlerInterceptor` and also the `PrincipalExtractor` and `AuthoritiesExtractor`.
The problem is, that I am just learning the Spring framework and these possibilities are overwhelming me.

It would be a plus if that method would allow some validation and would immediately respond with Error codes if the validation fails.

After that is achieved, I would like to add additional information to `MyCostumUserBean` from another server, which I send the identity of the current session's user to and receive e.g. Role/Permissions of that user.

I tried to put it in a picture:
[image]

### Question

1. What is the proper / by the Spring Framework intended way to deal with that? How do I achieve that?
2. Extra: Is it secure to rely on `OAuth2AuthorizedClient.getPrincipalName()`? Or can that be faked by an user, by faking the Cookie/Token?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the way to configure the success handler, or a filter which can check the user attributes.

If this is what you are asking, There are many ways to do it.
For examples:

Use User scope check:(need to assign the scope to the user in advance.)

```
 @ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/some/route")
    public String getSomeThing(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("custom") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        Set<String> scopes = authorizedClient.getAccessToken()
            .getScopes();
        if (scopes.contains("users:read")) {
         } else if (scopes.contains("users:read")) {
            return " page 1";
        } else {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Forbidden.");
        }
    }
```

You can put some logic in the successHandler:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**")
        .permitAll().and()
        .formLogin()
        .successHandler(successHandler());
}

@Bean
public CustomSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new CustomSuccessHandler();
}
```

If you want to apply a filter for your Security Chians:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    ...
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            ...
            .and() 
            .addFilterBefore(getBeforeAuthenticationFilter(), CustomBeforeAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage()
                .permitAll()
            ...
    }
     
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter getBeforeAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        CustomBeforeAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomBeforeAuthenticationFilter();
....
        return filter;
    }
     
}
```

You can also achieve the same purpose by using a Customizing Filter Chains, by give the different order and the relative login in it.

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10)
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapterForUserGroup1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     
     ...;
  }
}

@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10)
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapterForUserGroup2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     
     ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not really answer my question.

Comment: Or Maybe you just want to use:
@PreAuthorize(" ")
or
#@PostAuthorize("returnObject.get("first_name")== "testuser"")